# PHP error code: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, wordpress

When I search on my WordPress site I get the following error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in archive-product.php on line 20

Line 20 in that php file is

```
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this? For reference the immediate code before and after line 20 is below.

```
<?php //Display Page Header
    global $wp_query;
    $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
    echo page_header( get_post_meta($postid, 'qns_page_header_image', true) );
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Thank you,
Ryan

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So that means `$wp_query->post` is not an object.  I havn't used worpress much but It looks like one of the posts must be returning an empty object.

Try this in order to skip over any empty post:

```
<?php //Display Page Header
    global $wp_query;
    if(!empty($wp_query->post)){
        $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
        echo page_header( get_post_meta($postid, 'qns_page_header_image', true) );
    }
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. Unfortunately this code has a syntax error in

    if(!empty($wp_query->post){

Comment: Your code was missing one bracket but once I added it everything works great! I really appreciate your help!