# Using global and array together, property of non-object

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, global

**Solved, solution at the bottom of this post**

Since I've updated wordpress 4.9.1 to 4.9.2 I'm getting a:

*Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /url : eval()'d code on line 4*

The script still works, however I would like to get rid of the notice.
This is the script I'm using, the array defines the post ID's on which the visual editor should be disabled:

```
add_filter( 'user_can_richedit', 'disable_my_richedit' );
function disable_my_richedit( $default ) {
    global $post;
    if ( in_array( $post->ID, array(19909,20148,20150) ) )
        return false;
    return $default;
}
```

I tried this:

```
$post = array(19909,20148,20150);
global $post;
if ( in_array( $post->ID ));
```

But the message remains the same.
How can I use global and array() together without getting this error?
And why is the script working at all if it tries to get the property of a none-object?
I'm new to coding so I love to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: Have you tried using $post['ID'] instead of $post->ID?

Comment: Thnx Alan Berdinelli, I've just tried your suggestion, but doing so gives me another error when trying to visit the edit-page: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Post as array in /url : eval()'d code on line 5`

Comment: I would put `var_dump(__FILE__.__LINE__, $post);` immediately before the 'if' statement in the function `disable_my_richedit`. At least then you can see if it is an object. You must not set `$post` to an array outside the function or inside the function.

Comment: found another solution, see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it

**Solution:**

Found the solution over here: [PHP error code: Trying to get property of non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090956/php-error-code-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object)
The code now looks like this:

```
add_filter( 'user_can_richedit', 'disable_my_richedit' );
function disable_my_richedit( $default ) {
    global $post;
    if(!empty($post)){
        if ( in_array( $post->ID, array(19909,20148,20150) ) )
        return false;
        return $default;
    }
}
```

So it looks if `$post` is empty and skips over it when empty.